# accumulatedWeight unusable due to weird asserts?

Tags: c++, opencv

accumulatedWeight seems to have contradictory asserts for me. Here is the relevant section of my program :

```
console() << "newImg size : " << newImg.size() << "newImg channels : "  
          << newImg.channels() << "newImg type : " << newImg.type() << endl;

console() << "matsAvg size : " << mMatsAvg.size() << "matsAvg channels : "
          << mMatsAvg.channels() << "matsAvg type : " << mMatsAvg.type() << endl;

cv::accumulateWeighted(newImg, mMatsAvg, 0.3);
```

This outputs :

```
newImg size : [320 x 240] newImg channels : 1 newImg type : 0
matsAvg size : [320 x 240] matsAvg channels : 1 matsAvg type : 5
```

Side note : this means newImg is of type CV_8UC1 and matsAvg is of type CV_32F.

I get the following error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_ARE_TYPES_EQ(src, dsl) 
&& CV_MAT_TYPE(src->type == CV_8UC1) in unknown function, 
file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp, line 2414
```

This makes no sense. accumulateWeighted requires an 8 bit float as source and a 32 bit float as destination or the function doesn't work (that is, I get a failed assert (func !=0)). Yet, the above assert requires the source to be 8 bit AND the destination to be the same type as the source.

Unless I got something wrong?